# React: Why the count values are different in useEffect and inc event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the below code snippet, the component is rendered thrice when user clicks on the button but the count values remain the same.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const wait = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('rerendered');
    console.log(count);
  });

  const inc = async () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setCount(count + 5);

    await wait();

    console.log(count);
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log(count);
    setCount(count + 2);
    console.log(count);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={inc}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I know that first two `setCount()` are batched and after `await` they are not batched. If I use `setCount(prev => prev +1)`, I will get the updated values but my question is

**Why are the `count` values different in `inc()` and `useEffect()`? When does the `count` value actually changes coz certainly not on re-render?**

Comment: useEffect checks when state changes and logs it, your inc fn does not. All setState code is async, so you will not see the changes right away.

Comment: `useEffect()` is called before the `setCount(count + 2)` line in `inc()` but still the value in `inc()` is not the updated one, why? Are they accessing different `count` values?

Comment: Take a look at this. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short explanation**:

The `count` value of `0` is closed over the `inc` function at the moment of execution (i.e. the moment the user pressed the *Increment* button). This is because the `inc` function opens a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) with a "frozen" value of `0`. Therefore, `count` will always have the value `0` inside of the event handler function and all of the `setCount` calls will use a `count` value of `0` (even if the screen re-renders in-between).

The `useEffect` hook is called **after** React rendered. Therefore you'll there log the updated value (after `setCount` was called) each time.

The `setCount` calls which happen after 2 seconds will however still use the "old" `count` value of `0` each time because that's the value which got frozen in the `inc` closure.

---

**Detailed explanation of your code**:

I added some string arguments to your `console.log` statements to better differentiate between them:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const wait = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rerendered - useEffect", count);
  });

  const inc = async () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setCount(count + 5);

    await wait();

    console.log("inc 1", count);
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log("inc 2", count);
    setCount(count + 2);
    console.log("inc 3", count);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={inc}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This gives me the following console output when pressing the *Increment* button once:

[image: console log output]

**Explanation:**

1. **"rerendered - useEffect `0`"**: `useEffect` is called on mount of the component with the initial value `0` of the `count` state.
2. **"rerendered - useEffect `5`"**: Right after pressing `Increment` the two batched `setCount` calls cause the value to be `5` and re-render.
3. Now the `inc` function waits for 2 seconds.
4. **inc 1 `0`**: After 2 seconds the async function continues its execution and this log is called.
5. **inc 2 `0`**: The `setCount` call right after **inc 1 `0`** is called before this `console.log` statement, but executed asynchronously, so it will run after all synchronous tasks (this log), but before the next asynchronous task.
6. **"rerendered - useEffect `1`"**: `setCount` caused a re-render. `2` is shown in the UI and the `useEffect` is executed with this new value `2`. Why is the value not `7` (i.e. `5 + 2`)? - Because the `inc` function closes over the `count` value at the moment its called (i.e. when the user pressed the *Increment* button). Even new `re-renders` won't alter the `count` **inside** of the closure.
7. **inc 4 `0`**: Execution continues and the local "frozen" `count` value gets printed to the screen.
8. **"rerendered - useEffect `1`"**: Same explanation as point 6.

Play around with the code in [this CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-count-batching-nz2z7)

Also check out [this great article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-everything) about the `useEffect` hook which explains its relation with JavaScript closures really well.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for such an amazing and detailed explanation and there cannot be a better explanation than this. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Your explanation is very good but what did you mean by frozen ? how react freeze it actually or event handler closes over a frozen object that nothing can change it during the execution of that function?

Comment: I Understand now from great article you offer that said:
We already know that count is constant within a particular component render. Event handlers “see” the count state from the render that they “belong” to because count is a variable in their scope. The same is true for effects!

It’s not the count variable that somehow changes inside an “unchanging” effect. It’s the effect function itself that’s different on every render.

Comment: The event handler function creates a [JavaScript closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It's not a React feature, but a JavaScript feature. React function components just heavily rely on closures (as it's also discussed in the linked article).
Yes, at the moment the `inc` function is called, it "sees" the count value of `0`. So one says that the `inc` function "closed" over the count value (a.k.a. the count value got "frozen" as I like to call it). I found that using the word "freeze" makes explaining closures more intuitive

Comment: So event handler closes over particular render state, for example if we have 10 setState that causes 10 different renders , the event handler closes over specific render execution context that has a specific state, so if that state changes during async call its not affect that.

Comment: @Andru nicely explained, now pass an empty array `[]` to the useEffect hook & also pass `[count]` & see what happens. In the former useEffect will run just once on mount of the component and in the latter it is called every time count changes which in this specific instance should be exactly as you have it.